# Warning en una petición Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Esta es mi llamada ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'signs', 'action' => 'registros2')); ?>',
        headers : {
        },
        data:{
        fecha:$fecha
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) 
        {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        },
        success(msg){
        if (msg == 1){
            document.getElementById('contenedorregistro').innerHTML="<div clas='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>No se han encontrado ningun registro para la fecha especificada</div></div>";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('contenedorregistro').innerHTML=msg;
        }
        },
        error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
        //alert("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);
        console.log(errorMessage);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(xhr);
        }
     });
```

Y esta es mi función dentro de mi controlador, no se si es la manera más optima para hacerlo.

```
public function registros2(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $fecha = $this->request->getData()['fecha'];
    $fecha = getDate(strtotime($fecha));
    $contenido="";
    $registros = $this->Signs->find('all',['contain'=>array(
        'Users',
        'Users.Photos',
        'ProyectosCategoriasTareas',
        'ProyectosCategoriasTareas.Proyectos',
        'ProyectosCategoriasTareas.Tareas.Categorias'),
        'conditions' => array(
        'date_inicio BETWEEN "'.$fecha['year'].'-'.$fecha['mon'].'-'.$fecha['mday'].' 00:00:00" and "'.$fecha['year'].'-'.$fecha['mon'].'-'.$fecha['mday'].' 23:59:59"'
        )])->order('user_id');

    foreach  ($registros as $registro)
    {
        if(isset($actual))
        {
            if($actual == $registro->user_id)
            {
                if($registro->descripcion != '' && $registro->descripcion != null)
                {
                    $incidencia ="<a href='/signs/view/".$registro->id."'><span class='label label-danger'>Incidencia</span><br><span>".$registro->descripcion."</a>";
                }
                else{
                    $incidencia ="";
                }
                $contenido.= "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->proyecto->name."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->tarea->categoria->name."</td>
                        <td>".$incidencia."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->tarea->name."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->date_inicio."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->date_fin."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->created."</td>
                        <td>borrar</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
            else
            {
                if($registro->descripcion != '' && $registro->descripcion != null)
                {
                    $incidencia ="<a href='/etd/signs/view/".$registro->id."'><span class='label label-danger'>Incidencia</span><br><span>".$registro->descripcion."</a>";
                }
                else{
                    $incidencia ="";
                }
                $contenido.= "</tbody>
                </table>";
                //echo $contenido;
                $actual = $registro->user_id;
                $contenido.="
                <div class='col-md-10 panel-heading activestate' style='background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f83f37, #ab26aa) !important;'>
                <a style='color:white'>".$registro->user->name."</a>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-2'></div>
                <table class='table  display table-hover mb-30 dataTable no-footer'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NOMBRE PROYECTO</td>
                            <td>CATEGORIA</td>
                            <td>INCIDENCIA</td>
                            <td>TAREA</td>
                            <td>HORA DE INICIO</td>
                            <td>HORA DE FIN</td>
                            <td>FECHA</td>
                            <td>ACCION</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->proyecto->name."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->tarea->categoria->name."</td>
                        <td>".$incidencia."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->tarea->name."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->date_inicio."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->date_fin."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->created."</td>
                        <td>borrar</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($registro->descripcion != '' && $registro->descripcion != null)
                {
                    $incidencia ="<a href='/etd/signs/view/".$registro->id."'><span class='label label-danger'>Incidencia</span><br><span>".$registro->descripcion."</a>";
                }
                else{
                    $incidencia ="";
                }
            $actual = $registro->user_id;
            $contenido.="
                <div class='col-md-10 panel-heading activestate' style='background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f83f37, #ab26aa) !important;'>
                <a style='color:white'>".$registro->user->name."</a>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-2'></div>
                <table class='table  display table-hover mb-30 dataTable no-footer'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NOMBRE PROYECTO</td>
                            <td>CATEGORIA</td>
                            <td>INCIDENCIA</td>
                            <td>TAREA</td>
                            <td>HORA DE INICIO</td>
                            <td>HORA DE FIN</td>
                            <td>FECHA</td>
                            <td>ACCION</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->proyecto->name."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->tarea->categoria->name."</td>
                        <td>".$incidencia."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->proyectos_categorias_tarea->tarea->name."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->date_inicio."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->date_fin."</td>
                        <td>".$registro->created."</td>
                        <td>borrar</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
        }

    }
    if($contenido == ""){
        $contenido = '1';
    }
    else{
        $contenido.= "
        </tbody>
        </table>
    ";
    }
   echo $contenido;
}
```

Y esto me devuelve el html que he generado de forma correcta lo que me pasa es que al final, me muestra los siguientes warning y no se a que se debe

Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=/var/www/vhosts/proyecto/src/Controller/SignsController.php line=419 [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 51]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/proyecto/src/Controller/SignsController.php:419) [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 152]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/proyecto/src/Controller/SignsController.php:419) [CORE/src/

Pero solo me los muestra cuando en el html hay varias tablas, cuando no hay muchas no me aparece.

Comment: El problema es **la forma en que tienes organizados tus archivos**. Explícanos cómo se llama cada archivo para poder ayudarte a encontrar el fallo. El warning dice que los header fueron enviados en la línea `419` de `SignsController.php` y que estás tratando de enviar header de nuevo en la línea `51` de `ResponseEmitter.php`. Pues eso, tienes que organizar tu código de forma que los header no se manden dos veces desde dos partes distintas. Sin saber qué es cada archivo y qué lógica estás implementando, poco podemos hacer.

Comment: OJO: los header se envían cuando hay salida por pantalla aunque no indiques de forma explícita algo como `header(...)` de modo que ese warning ocurre también en escenarios donde primero sacas algo por pantalla y luego tratas de mandar un `header (...)`. O sea, tu código tiene que estar organizado de tal modo que **antes de enviar `header(...)` no salga absolutamente nada por pantalla**. Eso incluye todos los archivos que agregues con `include, require` etc, código HTML, un simple espacio en blanco no controlado, caracteres BOM (ocultos en el código), etc.

Comment: Mi archivo donde esta la funcion registro 2 se llama SignsController.php y la llamada ajax se encuentra en mi registros.ctp dodne al hacer click a un boton almaceno la fecha de un input y se lo envio por ajax para realizar las operaciones en mi funcion registro2 de mi SignsController. Y la linea 419 es el echo $contenido que hago en mi funcion registro2 para luego obtenerlo en el succes de mi peticion ajax

Comment: El mensaje de error habla también de un archivo `ResponseEmitter.php` que no has mencionado... Este tipo de errores es fácil de detectar, sólo tienes que revisar la cadena de llamadas y los archivos que se van incluyendo. Eso es parte de saber cómo está organizado tu código